# Adding User id to the URL dynamically in Lightning component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, lightning, visualforce-component, lightning-experience

I am not able to get the user id to get concatenated at the end of the URL for the profile.

Controller class:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static User getUser() {
    User myUser = [SELECT Id, Name 
            FROM User WHERE Id =: UserInfo.getUserId() LIMIT 1];

    if(myUser != NULL){
        System.debug('User: ' +myUser);
        return myUser;  
    } else{
        return NULL;
    }
 }
```

Component's JSController: I have implemented doInit method to initialize User object on the Component and have the user name in the Menu.

Cmp:

```
<li><ui:outputText value="{!v.user.Name}"/> 

                      <lightning:buttonMenu iconName="utility:down" name="Menu" iconSize="small" onselect="{!c.handleMenuSelect }">
                        <lightning:menuItem label="My Profile" value="Profile"/>
                        <lightning:menuItem label="Logout" value="Logout"/>
                      </lightning:buttonMenu>
                </li>
```

CmpJs

```
handleMenuSelect: function(cmp, event, helper) {

    var selectedMenuItemValue = event.getParam("value");
    if(selectedMenuItemValue == 'Profile'){
         var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
         urlEvent.setParams({
             "url": '/profile/' + component.get("v.user.Id")
         });
         urlEvent.fire();  
    } else if(selectedMenuItemValue == 'Logout'){
       var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
         urlEvent.setParams({
             "url": '/logout' 
         });
         urlEvent.fire(); 
    }
    console.log(selectedMenuItemValue);
}
})
```

Comment: By the way, your method should really just be written as: `@AuraEnabled public static User getUser() { return [SELECT Name FROM User WHERE Id =: UserInfo.getUserId()]; }`

Comment: @sfdcfox 
Sure. I would remove the If-else statements. I think I might need **Id** field in the Select statement, as I need it to concatenate with profile URL. Correct me if I am wrong. Thanks

Comment: You get Id "for free" whenever you do a query. There's no need to explicitly mention it unless it's the only field you're querying.

Comment: @sfdcfox Sounds good.
 Could you please help me in solving my issue? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
         "url": '/profile/' + component.get("v.user.Id")
```

You should retrieve the attribute by its name and the go from there:

```
         "url": '/profile/' + component.get("v.user").Id
```

Also, make sure the function's parameter matches the variable name you're using:

```
handleMenuSelect: function(component, event, helper) {
```

Comment: Here is my doInit method JSController:
     `({
 doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
  var action = component.get("c.getUser");
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS") {
            component.set("v.user", response.getReturnValue());
        }
        else {
            console.log("Failed with state: " + state);
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);},`

Comment: Yayyy! It worked. Thank you so much. \m/ 
My bad, I didn't see the silly mistake I did with the function's parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are passing in `cmp` to your `handleMenuSelect` function, but trying to reference it as `component` ...

try this:

```
urlEvent.setParams({
 "url": '/profile/' + cmp.get("v.user.Id")
})
```

Comment: Component seems to be working fine for logout URL. So I don't think I am using a incorrect reference.

Comment: I apologize. I realized what you just said. Thank you for that. :)